# How to calculate AIC for quasibinomial models?

Tags: r, regression, glm

Let's take data :

```
binary_var <- sample(0:1, 100, replace = T)
indep_var <- rnorm(100)
```

And let's consider model output of logit regression :

```
glm(binary_var~indep_var, family = quasibinomial(link = 'logit'))

Call:  glm(formula = binary_var ~ indep_var, family = quasibinomial(link = "logit"))

Coefficients:
(Intercept)    indep_var  
    0.04441     -0.09845  

Degrees of Freedom: 99 Total (i.e. Null);  98 Residual
Null Deviance:      138.6 
Residual Deviance: 138.3    AIC: NA
```

As you can see, AIC is calculated as 'NA'. I've read about this and it seems that AIC cannot be calculated easily for quasibinomial models. I also found package `AICcmodavg` which should allowed me to calculate wanted AIC. However I couldn't find proper function in this package which would allowed me to do so. Could you please help with me with calculating AIC for quasibinomial models ?